# How to add elements to an object list in java

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public class Bus{
    private int seats;
    private List<People> currentPeople;
    
    public Bus(int seats){
      this.seats = seats;
    }
    
    public void passengers(List<People> boarders, List<People> deboarders){
    this.currentPeople.remove(deboarders);
    this.currentPeople.add(boarders);
    }
```

I'm trying to create a list of people on the bus. I'm trying to remove deboarders(alighting passengers) from the list and add the boarders(boarding passengers). But Java won't let me add the boarders to the currentPeople list. People is a class which stores the name and ticket number of the passanger. Any help on this? I've been trying to solve this for hours.

Comment: FYI `People` is a class, not a constructor

Answer (score 3):

To add a collection of objects to a list you need to use `addAll`:

```
this.currentPeople.addAll(boarders);
```

To remove a collection of objects from a list you need to use `removeAll`:

```
this.currentPeople.removeAll(deboarders);
```

Be careful, in order to compare and remove the right elements from the list, `removeAll` uses `equals` method. So you should implement `equals` method in your `People` class.

**EDIT:**

`equals` method for People class:

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        People people = (People) o;

        if (ticketNumber != people.ticketNumber) return false;
        return name != null ? name.equals(people.name) : people.name == null;
    }
```

Don't forget to initialize `currentPeople` list, otherwise you will get `NullPointerException`.

Comment: `@Override
public boolean equals(People other) { if (other.getTicketNumber()==this.ticketNumber) {return true;} else {  return false;} }`

I can't understand why java doesn't let me run this?

Comment: You should give us the People class to give you the proper equals. Try to edit your question by adding People class.

Comment: Done please check

Comment: @fps Thank you for your remarks, I have edited the answer.

Comment: @Ismail Great! I had already upvoted your answer, I think it should be accepted by now

Answer (score 0):

Change add to addAll and likewise for remove.
As Federico points out in comments, assuming People has equals method implemented.

Comment: Assuming `People` has a properly implemented `equals` method, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try removeAll() and addAll() methods because you are passing a Collection as a parameter.

Do not forget " ; " at the end of the line inside your constructor.

```
this.currentPeople.removeAll(deboarders);
this.currentPeople.addAll(boarders);
```